# Order results in left join with db_query()

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, sql-order-by

I'm working on this query for a Drupal 7 project:

```
$group = taxonomy_get_tree(2);
$group_list = "";
$total_countries_list = "";
foreach ($group as $member) {

$countries_list = "";
$id = str_replace(' ', '-', $member->name);
$id = str_replace('/', '-', $id);
$group_list .= '<li><a id="link-' . str_replace(' ', '-', $id) . '" href="#">. ' . $member->name . '</a></li>';

$results = db_query('SELECT n.title AS name, fdfea.field_email_address_value AS email 
    FROM node AS n 
    LEFT JOIN field_data_field_email_address AS fdfea ON fdfea.entity_id = n.nid 
    LEFT JOIN field_data_field_group_of_countries AS fdfgoc ON fdfgoc.field_group_of_countries_tid = :country_taxonomy 
    WHERE n.nid = fdfgoc.entity_id', array(':country_taxonomy' => $member->tid));

$i = 0;
foreach ($results as $country) {
  if ($i % 13 == 0){
    $countries_list .= '</ul><ul>';
  }
  $countries_list .= '<li><a href="mailto:' . $country->email . '">' . $country->name . '</a></li>';
  $i++;
}
$countries_list = '<ul>' . $countries_list . '</ul>';
  $total_countries_list .= '<div class="countries-list" id="' . $id . '">' . $countries_list . '</div>';
 }
 $total_countries_list = '<div class="countries-wrapper">' . $total_countries_list . '</div>';
 $group_list = '<ul class="big-list">' . $group_list . '</ul>';
 return $group_list . $total_countries_list;
```

I'm using the results of this query to form lists of countries. The query works fine but I also need to sort countries in each group alphabetically. ORDER BY is apparently not the way to do so so how can I do the sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you say you can't use `ORDER BY`.

Assuming the country name is in `node.title` and there is a group id of some sort in the `field_data_field_group_of_countries` table (I'm just going to guess something like `gid`), then surely you could use an `ORDER BY` clause something like this:

```
ORDER BY fdfgoc.gid, n.title
```

So it would order first by the country group, and then by country name in each group.

Comment: Yes, country name is node.title. Group id in the field_data_field_group_of_countries table is field_group_of_countries_tid as seen in the query.
Adding

    ORDER BY fdfgoc.field_group_of_countries_tid, n.title

at the end of the query triggers a 

    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

in the line of the order by.

Comment: Unexpected T_STRING is a PHP syntax error - I don't see how that can have anything to do with the validity of the sql query. Did you add it immediately after the WHERE clause before the close quote? Otherwise I have no idea - I can't reproduce that error.

Comment: You're right, this was very frustrating - for some reason I was placing the order by just after the quote!!! Thank you & apologies for the time spent on that.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you got it sorted out.